# Not able to use Drools Audit View in Eclipse Oxygen and STS 4

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, drools

I am trying to use Drools Audit View in STS 4 (Version: 4.3.1.RELEASE) /Eclipse Oxygen (March 2018 release). I have Eclipse/STS and installed Drools 7.3.o.Final plugin and drools rule is working fine. However, I need to use Audit View so that I can see the activation and othe related information. However, there is no information showing in Drools Audit View in eclipse. 
I ran the java class as Drools application and also dialect is "java" in .drl file along with breakpoint in "then" section of rule.

Please guide.

P.S : Though I tried with available option for audit view, I am not able to achieve so that I am posting here. 
If some one want to down vote, please mention the reason so that least I know why this is down voted.

Thanks
Kumar Shorav

Comment: Eclipse Neon is pretty old (6 releases behind). Can you reproduce this issue with the current version of Eclipse and of the Drools plug-in?

Comment: @howlger I also checked it on Oxygen- March 2018 release. Thanks

Comment: @howlger I am using STS 4 (Version: 4.3.1.RELEASE) and it is not working as well.

Comment: Oxygen is also outdated and a couple releases behind. The current Eclipse version is 2019-06 (4.12).

Comment: @howlger Now, I tested with latest version too. I ran as Drools Application and started debugging. Also put breakpoint on rules but in AUDIT view is always without any log or information. I don't know, is it a bug or I am not doing it in a right way.

Comment: Have a look at option 2 at the following specifically "utilise the Drools KieRuntimeLogger to track the audit events in the runtime during rule execution. The file created by this logger can then be passed to the Drools Audit viewer in Eclipse for analysis. " from https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2016/08/12/get-it-done-with-these-5-techniques-to-debug-your-jboss-brms-applications/